# How to modify a general css using javascript and jquery and return the result as a new id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have CSS with ids like this:

```
<style>

.HIDE-DISPLAY-k {
    background-color: orange;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#SHOW-DISPLAY-k {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    width: 70%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.BUTTON-k {
    background-color: orange;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

</style>

im  calling it from   javascript file like this

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/sliding_Documents.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(docProperty) {
    docProperty='|FROM_top|width|10|height|1500|top|30|bottom|""|left|500|right|""|'
    sliding_NotePads(docProperty);
    });
</script>
<a class="BUTTON-k" href="#"><button>NOTEPAD</button></a>
<div class="hidden_SHOW-DISPLAY" ></div>
<div  id="SHOW-DISPLAY-k"></div>


//the docProperty is  just  an array where i  put the  specific values to use in changing css like  width, height.
```

The javascript sliding_Documents.js is

```
function sliding_NotePads(docProperty) {
/*without clicking the hide-display-k is in place and  nothing can be seen.
 on click the  if condition defines  how the display appears*/

$('.HIDE-DISPLAY-k').hide()


/*get the information added to the  button to customise the display window*/
$('.BUTTON-k').click(function () {
    var css_changes = docProperty.split("|");

    // docProperty='|FROM|right|width|100|height|50|top|30|bottom|""|right|20|left|""|'
    //this is where i make changes to the css
    $("#DISPLAY-k").css({//or use this format $("#DISPLAY-k").css("top", 10);
        width: css_changes[css_changes.indexOf("width") + 1],
        height: css_changes[css_changes.indexOf("height") + 1],
        top: css_changes[css_changes.indexOf("top") + 1],
        bottom: css_changes[css_changes.indexOf("bottom") + 1],
        left: css_changes[css_changes.indexOf("left") + 1],
        right: css_changes[css_changes.indexOf("right") + 1]
    });

    if(css_changes[1]==="FROM_top"|| css_changes[1]==="FROM_bottom"){
     $('#SHOW-DISPLAY-k').css('z-index', 2).slideToggle("slow");
     };

     if(css_changes[1]==="FROM_left"|| css_changes[1]==="FROM_right"){
     $('#SHOW-DISPLAY-k').css('z-index', 2).animate({width: 'toggle'}, "slow")
     };
    });
};
```

How can I call back the  changes in the #SHOW-DISPLAY-k and  give it a new  ID or name so that it only affects one thing and not other things in the html?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your HTML, please?

Comment: In the first file is the html, the css is included using <style></style>. thanks

Comment: Sorry - dopey me I didn't scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is some strange case mixing for class names and function names. To each their own, I suppose. Anyway!

I think you might want `.clone()`

```
var newDiv = $('#SHOW-DISPLAY-k').clone();

// do whatever, ex: give it a new id and append it to body
newDiv.attr('id', 'SHOW-DISPLAY-x');
$('body').append(newDiv);
```

Though I'm not sure I 100% understood your question. Does this accomplish what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks unfortunately it seems  not to work when it try <script>
    var newDiv = $('#SHOW-DISPLAY-k').clone();
</script>
<button onclick="alert($('#newDiv ').height());">Show3</button>

Comment: That's because `newDiv` is not the ID. Read the rest of my code, I even explain it in a comment

Comment: I have found a method to  use class instade of id, that way I can remove old class and  add a new one. PROBLEM, how can I call back the results from external .js file

Comment: External will not matter provided you're importing the script correctly.